# Logcat not showing exception stack trace

Tags: android, exception, logging, adt, logcat

Logcat prints a single line with just the message and no exception stack trace. I am passing the exception `e` to the `Log.i` function. It used to work before. Now I can only see the stack trace using `e.printStackTrace()` which prints it to system.err.

```
catch (final IOException e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Error connecting to server.", e);
}
```

I think it may be because my current project is an Android Library and not an Application.

It's supposed to look like this but instead I only get the very first line. In my case it says "Error connecting to server." in place of "FATAL EXCEPTION: main".
[image: Logcat Stack Trace]

Comment: Why not e.printStackTrace();

Comment: It's not suitable for Android.

Comment: Try this Log.i("Error : " , "Message is :-  " + e.getMessage());

Comment: You are just printing an exception for getting message you should have called getmessage().

Comment: I'm passing the exception `e` to the Log function. It's supposed to print the stack trace automatically like it used to.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. I'm curious if you ever solved it?

Comment: Never solved it. I've long since formatted my PC.